# MongoDB aggregation performance issue using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, performance

I'm having some issue about MongoDB aggregation performance.

My database has 43'000'000 document and when I'm trying to call the backend it never responds (I'm sure the issue is from the DB, with a smaller set of documents everything is working fine).

I'm actually using Node.js and it's Mongoose module.

This is a sample of the model

```
var PingSchema = new Schema({
    provider: String,
    from_zone: String,
    to_zone: String,
    from_host: String,
    to_host: String,
    icmp_seq: Number,
    ttl: Number,
    time: Number,
    timestamp: { type : Date, default: Date.now }
}).plugin(mongoosePaginate);

const Ping = mongoose.model('Ping', PingSchema);
```

I'm using Express to create some routes and this is the code of the two main queries from backend

```
router.route('/pings/query/avgOfEveryPingOfSelectedDate').get(async (req, res, next) => {
    var start, end, sameRegion;

    start = new Date(req.query.start + "T00:00:00-00:00");
    end = new Date(req.query.end + "T23:59:59-00:00");
    sameRegion = parseInt(req.query.sameRegion);

    Ping.aggregate()
    .project({sameRegion: {$cmp: ['$from_zone', '$to_zone']}, provider: "$provider", time: "$time", timestamp: "$timestamp"})
    .match({$and: [{sameRegion: sameRegion}, {timestamp: {$gte: start, $lte: end}}]})
    .group({_id : "$provider", avg: { $avg: "$time" }, count: { $sum: 1 }})
    .exec(function (err, resp) {
        if (err) {
            // TODO
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(resp);
        }
    })
});

router.route('/pings/query/avgOfEveryDayOfSelectedYear').get(async (req, res, next) => {
    var year, provider, sameRegion;

    year = parseInt(req.query.year);
    provider = req.query.provider;
    sameRegion = parseInt(req.query.sameRegion);

Ping.aggregate()
    .project({sameRegion: {$cmp: ['$from_zone', '$to_zone']}, provider: "$provider", time: "$time", timestamp: "$timestamp", "year": {"$year":"$timestamp"}, "dayOfYear": { "$dayOfYear": "$timestamp" }})
    .match({$and: [{sameRegion: sameRegion}, {year: year}, {provider: provider}]})
    .group({_id : {"provider": "$provider", "dayOfYear": "$dayOfYear"}, avg: { $avg: "$time" }, count: { $sum: 1 }})
    .sort({"_id": 1})
    .exec(function (err, resp) {
        if (err) {
            // TODO
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(resp);
        }
    })
});
```

The first query takes in input two dates and return the average time of all pings in this range. The second one takes a year and a selected provider (a simple string) and returns the average of all pings matching the conditions.

I'm asking if is my code wrong (or it needs some optimizations) or if I should do some thing of cacheing or parallelization (maybe MongoDB has some features about that?).

Thanks everyone in advance.

**EDIT** 1: 
Maybe allowDiskOption or some indexes are useful?

**EDIT** 2:
I've implemented allowDiskOption and some indexes on provider and timestamp, but the query are still slow.
The problem is **here**: these query are too slow on this big dataset.

```
// By day in month
db.pings.aggregate(
    [
        {$project: {month: {"$month":"$timestamp"}}},
        {$match: {$and: [{provider: "AWS"},{month:8}]}},
        {$group:{_id: {"$dayOfYear":"$timestamp"}, avg: {$avg:"$time"}}},
        {$sort:{_id:1}}
    ],
    {
        allowDiskUse: true
    }
)

// In two dates
db.pings.aggregate(
    [
        {$match:{timestamp:{$gte:ISODate("2018-08-10T00:00:00.0Z"), $lte:ISODate("2018-08-18T23:59:59.0Z")}}},
        {$group:{_id: "$provider", avg: {$avg:"$time"}}}
    ],
    {
        allowDiskUse: true
    }
)
```

What I'm asking now is: **How can i optimize these queries?**

Thanks again

Comment: Have you tried feeding the query directly into mongo and seeing how long it takes?

Comment: @Skami Yes, they take the exact time, it's not a problem from the middleware.